# No fluent-plugin-splunk-hec plugin found while using splunk/fluentd-hec Docker image

Tags: docker, splunk, fluentd, splunk-hec, fluent-plugin-splunk-hec

I'm looking for a Docker image of Fluentd with `fluent-plugin-splunk-hec` plugin to send data to Splunk.

I found that some time ago [Fluentd provided such an image](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/blob/master/archived-image/v0.12/debian-splunkhec/Dockerfile), but it's discontinued for some/no reason. Fluentd [official documentation](https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/output/splunk) points at the [outdated repository](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-splunk) as well.

Finally, I found something promising at [Docker Hub `splunk/fluentd-hec`](https://hub.docker.com/r/splunk/fluentd-hec/tags) which states:

> By splunk • Updated 24 minutes ago This image contains fluentd along
> with the fluent-plugin-splunk-hec.

When I tried to use this image to send data to Splunk like this:

```
<match **>
   @type splunk_hec
   hec_host XX.XX.XX.XX
   hec_port 8088
   hec_token 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
</match>
```

I received an error message:

```
2022-08-09 10:12:55 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: parsing config file is succeeded path="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf"
2022-08-09 10:12:55 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-concat' version '2.4.0'
2022-08-09 10:12:55 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-jq' version '0.5.1'
2022-08-09 10:12:55 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter' version '2.9.4'
2022-08-09 10:12:55 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus' version '2.0.2'
2022-08-09 10:12:55 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-record-modifier' version '2.1.0'
2022-08-09 10:12:55 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-systemd' version '1.0.2'
2022-08-09 10:12:55 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluentd' version '1.14.6'
2022-08-09 10:12:55 +0000 [error]: fluent/log.rb:372:error: config error file="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf" error_class=Fluent::NotFoundPluginError error="Unknown output plugin 'splunk_hec'. Run 'gem search -rd fluent-plugin' to find plugins"
```

When I checked the image itself I found that there's no `fluent-plugin-splunk-hec` plugin available inside.

There's yet another option available - build own image using [this repo](https://github.com/splunk/fluent-plugin-splunk-hec), but maybe I missed something important.

**EDIT**

I've created a new image using https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/blob/master/docker-image/v1.15/debian-stackdriver/Dockerfile, but added plugin to the [Gemfile](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/blob/master/docker-image/v1.15/debian-stackdriver/Gemfile) as a single line `gem "fluent-plugin-splunk-hec"`. It works as expected:

```
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: parsing config file is succeeded path="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf"
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluentd' version '1.15.1'
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-concat' version '2.5.0'
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions' version '0.0.14'
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-google-cloud' version '0.4.10'
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-grok-parser' version '2.6.2'
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-json-in-json-2' version '1.0.2'
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter' version '2.13.0'
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-multi-format-parser' version '1.0.0'
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-parser-cri' version '0.1.1'
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus' version '2.0.3'
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-record-modifier' version '2.1.0'
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter' version '2.4.0'
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-splunk-hec' version '1.2.13'
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-systemd' version '1.0.5'
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [debug]: fluent/log.rb:309:debug: No fluent logger for internal event
2022-08-11 12:34:22 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: using configuration file: <ROOT>
```

In compare to the example above you can clearly see that `fluent-plugin-splunk-hec` plugin was loaded.

**/EDIT**

What's wrong with the image from Splunk or with my config? What's the easiest way to make it working?

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Docker, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but troubleshooting a particular image, which makes it off-topic here.

Comment: I would most probably try to contact the developers through a [gitub issue](https://github.com/splunk/fluent-plugin-splunk-hec/issues).

Comment: It's a good idea, but TBH I doubt that the Docker image and the GitHub repo are supported by the same Development team.

Comment: Here you can find an issue report at GitHub https://github.com/splunk/fluent-plugin-splunk-hec/issues/252

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out the Docker image `splunk/fluentd-hec:1.2.13` uses bundle to start fluentd. So, instead of a command:

```
fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/fluent.conf  -v
```

you should use bundle:

```
bundle exec fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/fluent.conf
```

As a result, everything works as expected:

```
2022-08-16 13:03:28 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: parsing config file is succeeded path="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf"
2022-08-16 13:03:28 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluentd' version '1.14.6'
2022-08-16 13:03:28 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-concat' version '2.4.0'
2022-08-16 13:03:28 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-jq' version '0.5.1'
2022-08-16 13:03:28 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter' version '2.9.4'
2022-08-16 13:03:28 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus' version '2.0.2'
2022-08-16 13:03:28 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-record-modifier' version '2.1.0'
2022-08-16 13:03:28 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-splunk-hec' version '1.2.13'
2022-08-16 13:03:28 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:330:info: gem 'fluent-plugin-systemd' version '1.0.2'
2022-08-16 13:03:28 +0000 [debug]: fluent/log.rb:309:debug: No fluent logger for internal event
```